# Scroll and set div on top in modal-body when click on chosen container

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, jquery-chosen

I have one form in modal and i format my select box with chosen jquery

I want to scroll div to top of modal body when i click on chosen container

[My form is here](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/d0wyrys4/)

[image]

When clicking on chosen container i want this type of scroll by jquery

[image]

I tried to do like this:

```
//$(document).on('click','.search-field',function(){
$(document).on('click','.chosen-choices',function(){
    console.log("ok");
    // $(this).animate({scrollTop: $(this).closest('.modal-body').offset().top},'slow');
    // $('body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).closest('.modal-body').offset().top},'slow');
    $('.modal-body').animate({scrollTop: $(this).closest('.modal-body').offset().top},'slow');
    // $(this).closest('.chosen-container').animate({scrollTop: $(this).closest('.modal-body').offset().top},'slow');
    // $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

**If I click on the project manager select box, then it should be fixed on top and if I click on the subcontractor then it should be fixed on top.**

Please help me for doing this.

Comment: Try this.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });

Comment: Sorry.. not work@JazzCat..I provide fiddle also. Can you please check what's wrong?When i click on project manager select box it's scroll down insted of up.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/09vtg4ev/

Comment: Thankyou..Finally it solved@JazzCat

Comment: It scrolls little bit fast how can i make it smooth scroll..??Can i left some space on top for show label also?@JazzCat