# Implode array with skipping specific array items in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to implode array with skipping specific value.

My array is:

```
$unit = array("123","56","0","1","10","965","65","0"," ","63");
```

From above array I don't want 0(zero) and blank value while imploding, I tried this:

```
$implode1 = implode(",", array_filter($unit));

Output : 123,56,1,10,965,65, ,63 (Skipping 0 but not blank value)
```

I tried callback method of `array_filter` function

Below example, I tried to implode array and don't want 0, 1 and blank value

```
$implode1 = implode(",", array_filter($unit,function($v,$k){
    return $v != " " || $v != '1' || $v != '0';
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));

output : 123,56,0,1,10,965,65,0, ,63
```

Can anyone help me Where am i wrong in both methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `||`:

```
$implode1 = implode(",", array_filter($unit,function($v,$k){
    return $v != " " && $v != '1' && $v != '0';
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

But in your case it's better to convert values to int and check:

```
$implode1 = implode(",", array_filter($unit,function($v,$k){
    return (int)$v > 1;
},ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH));
```

Here zeroes and empty values (which will be converted to zero) or even non-numeric values (which will be converted to zero also) will be skipped. And as you don't need `1` too I added `greater than` check.

Also as you don't use `$k` in your function - you can skip it and `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` parameter.

Comment: Can you please help me for sort out this if you don't mind?[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299271/scroll-and-set-div-on-top-in-modal-body-when-click-on-chosen-container)